# Add Entity Reference to Drupal 8 Form Field?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-8

How can users add products to a simple plugin config using an autocomplete field?

I tried to use Config Entity but it looks the same as Form API (and I can't use entity fields there).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to do this in Drupal 8 using the form API and the entity_autocomplete type.

```
$form['stories'] = [
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#target_type' => 'node',
    '#title' => $this->t('Stories'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Select some stories.'),
    '#default_value' => $default_entities,
    '#tags' => TRUE,
    '#selection_settings' => array(
        'target_bundles' => array('page', 'article'),
    ),
    '#weight' => '0',
];
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. I completed that adding custom ContentEntityType. It's more complex though. But it also allow more flexibility.

Comment: You get a fist pump from me

Answer (score -1):

Use [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) - there is an entity reference field.
This won't be useable for your purpose .. but you can check the source for sake.

Comment: The question was asked on August 10, 2016, not on 2010.

Comment: true - and webform nor eform makes sense .. but it's a good alternative if someone wants to create a form via UI